# Weekly Report Generation in sql server with 7 tables which summarize in one table as maximum value of the day at 23:59:59 PM

Tags: sql, sql-server

In sql there are 7 tables for energy consumption which log the values every 15 min. i created one monthly template table which has daycol(1 to 31) days. Then i wrote one query in view section which extract 7 days from the monthly table :-

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       FORMAT(Localcol, 'yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59') AS LocalCol,
       FORMAT(Localcol, 'dd') AS DayCol
FROM (SELECT CONVERT(datetime, DATEADD(DAY, ABS(DayCol - FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()), 'dd')), DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()))) AS Localcol,
             DayCol
      FROM dbo.MonthlyTemplate) t
WHERE (LocalCol < GETDATE())
  AND (LocalCol > DATEADD(DAY, -8, GETDATE()));
```

After this i call this view query(Weekly Template View) in weekly energy report view as :-

```sql
SELECT a.LocalCol,
       b.STN_ESR_MDB1_IC1_Sensor,
       c.STN_ESR_EEPP_IC1_Sensor,
       d.STN_ESR_CPP_Sensor,
       e.STN_ESR_EPP_Sensor,
       f.STN_ESR_ESPP_Sensor,
       g.STN_ESR_MLP_Sensor
FROM dbo.Weekly_Template_View a
     INNER JOIN (SELECT dbo.Weekly_Template_View.DayCol,
                        COALESCE(t.STN_ESR_MDB1_IC1_Sensor, 0) AS STN_ESR_MDB1_IC1_Sensor
                 FROM (SELECT CAST(LocalCol AS date) AS LocalCol,
                              FORMAT(MAX(LocalCol), 'dd') AS sDay,
                              MAX(STN_ESR_MDB1_IC1_Sensor) AS STN_ESR_MDB1_IC1_Sensor
                       FROM dbo.STN_ESR_MDB1_IC1
                       WHERE (STN_ESR_MDB1_IC1_Sensor <> 0)
                       GROUP BY CAST(LocalCol AS date)) t
                      RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Weekly_Template_View ON t.sDay = dbo.Weekly_Template_View.DayCol) b ON a.DayCol = b.DayCol
     INNER JOIN (SELECT Weekly_Template_View_1.DayCol,
                        COALESCE(t_1.STN_ESR_EEPP_IC1_Sensor, 0) AS STN_ESR_EEPP_IC1_Sensor
                 FROM (SELECT CAST(LocalCol AS date) AS LocalCol,
                              FORMAT(MAX(LocalCol), 'dd') AS sDay,
                              MAX(STN_ESR_EEPP_IC1_Sensor) AS STN_ESR_EEPP_IC1_Sensor
                       FROM dbo.STN_ESR_EEPP_IC1
                       WHERE (STN_ESR_EEPP_IC1_Sensor <> 0)
                       GROUP BY CAST(LocalCol AS date)) t_1
                      RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Weekly_Template_View Weekly_Template_View_1 ON t_1.sDay = Weekly_Template_View_1.DayCol) c ON a.DayCol = c.DayCol
     INNER JOIN (SELECT Weekly_Template_View_2.DayCol,
                        COALESCE(t_2.STN_ESR_CPP_Sensor, 0) AS STN_ESR_CPP_Sensor
                 FROM (SELECT CAST(LocalCol AS date) AS LocalCol,
                              FORMAT(MAX(LocalCol), 'dd') AS sDay,
                              MAX(STN_ESR_CPP_Sensor) AS STN_ESR_CPP_Sensor
                       FROM dbo.STN_ESR_CPP
                       WHERE (STN_ESR_CPP_Sensor <> 0)
                       GROUP BY CAST(LocalCol AS date)) t_2
                      RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Weekly_Template_View Weekly_Template_View_2 ON t_2.sDay = Weekly_Template_View_2.DayCol) d ON a.DayCol = d.DayCol
     INNER JOIN (SELECT Weekly_Template_View_3.DayCol,
                        COALESCE(t_3.STN_ESR_EPP_Sensor, 0) AS STN_ESR_EPP_Sensor
                 FROM (SELECT CAST(LocalCol AS date) AS LocalCol,
                              FORMAT(MAX(LocalCol), 'dd') AS sDay,
                              MAX(STN_ESR_EPP_Sensor) AS STN_ESR_EPP_Sensor
                       FROM dbo.STN_ESR_EPP
                       WHERE (STN_ESR_EPP_Sensor <> 0)
                       GROUP BY CAST(LocalCol AS date)) t_3
                      RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Weekly_Template_View Weekly_Template_View_3 ON t_3.sDay = Weekly_Template_View_3.DayCol) e ON a.DayCol = e.DayCol
     INNER JOIN (SELECT Weekly_Template_View_4.DayCol,
                        COALESCE(t_4.STN_ESR_ESPP_Sensor, 0) AS STN_ESR_ESPP_Sensor
                 FROM (SELECT CAST(LocalCol AS date) AS LocalCol,
                              FORMAT(MAX(LocalCol), 'dd') AS sDay,
                              MAX(STN_ESR_ESPP_Sensor) AS STN_ESR_ESPP_Sensor
                       FROM dbo.STN_ESR_ESPP
                       WHERE (STN_ESR_ESPP_Sensor <> 0)
                       GROUP BY CAST(LocalCol AS date)) t_4
                      RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Weekly_Template_View Weekly_Template_View_4 ON t_4.sDay = Weekly_Template_View_4.DayCol) f ON a.DayCol = f.DayCol
     INNER JOIN (SELECT Weekly_Template_View_5.DayCol,
                        COALESCE(t_5.STN_ESR_MLP_Sensor, 0) AS STN_ESR_MLP_Sensor
                 FROM (SELECT CAST(LocalCol AS date) AS LocalCol,
                              FORMAT(MAX(LocalCol), 'dd') AS sDay,
                              MAX(STN_ESR_MLP_Sensor) AS STN_ESR_MLP_Sensor
                       FROM dbo.STN_ESR_MLP
                       WHERE (STN_ESR_MLP_Sensor <> 0)
                       GROUP BY CAST(LocalCol AS date)) t_5
                      RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Weekly_Template_View Weekly_Template_View_5 ON t_5.sDay = Weekly_Template_View_5.DayCol) g ON a.DayCol = g.DayCol;
```

I get the result till one month but when the query run on second month it showing the value of past month when the database created and same date it repeating the value again and again. Like today date is 8th of march so it showing same values and rows again and again.

Comment: I considerably doubt all those subqueries, with subqueries, and joins on a column with a `FORMAT` function applied are going to be performant. Looking at this query, I don't doubt you have gone down the completely wrong path to achieve what you *really* want. You'll likely going to be far better off explaining from the beginning.

Comment: Seems you are trying to pivot here - which would be more obvious if you gave your table useful aliases rather than single letters. The multiple references to the same table and the use of right joins indicates you need help as well. I suggest you start over with a query that will select the correct rows first. Get that working and THEN worry about the presentation. Better yet - do your pivot in a reporting tool that will make this easier.

Comment: i need data for last 7 days from current date from six tables. i get the data till one month (last 7 days).My query running without any error till the month end. help me to solve the issue asap